# How to change textfield property from 'onEditingFinished' in Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml, textfield

I am trying to alter the border color and width of my TextField depending on a vaildation check (javascript function that returns true if OK).  If the user enters an invalid date of birth I wish to colour the Textfield box border red.  Here is my qml definition:

```
        TextField{
            id: dob
            placeholderText: qsTr("dd-mm-yyyy")
            font.pixelSize: 14
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    id:dobstyle
                    radius: 2
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "black"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDate
            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                inputMask= "00-00-0000"
            }
            onEditingFinished: {
                var datesplit = dob.text.split("-");
                var jsDOB = new Date(datesplit[2],datesplit[1]-1,datesplit[0]);
                var logichk = (isValidDateLogical(jsDOB));
                var validchk = (isValidDate(dob.text))
                if(!validchk || !logichk)
                {
                    dobstyle.border.color="red"
                    dobstyle.border.width=3
                }
            }
            selectByMouse: true
        }
```

I am getting 'ReferenceError: dobstyle is not defined'  Any idea how best to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextFieldStyle` is a component, and what is inside does not exist for outside, what you must do is create a property in the `TextField` and make a binding, then only modify the property:

```
...
Layout.fillWidth: true
property color bordercolor: "black" // <---
property int borderwidth: 1 // <---
style: TextFieldStyle {
    textColor: "black"
    background: Rectangle {
        id:dobstyle
        radius: 2
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 24
        border.color: dob.bordercolor // <---
        border.width: dob.borderwidth // <---
    }
}
...
onEditingFinished: {
    var datesplit = dob.text.split("-");
    var jsDOB = new Date(datesplit[2],datesplit[1]-1,datesplit[0]);
    var logichk = isValidDateLogical(jsDOB));
    var validchk = (isValidDate(dob.text))
    if(!validchk || !logichk)
    {
        dob.bordercolor ="red" // <---
        dob.borderwidth = 3 // <---
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, I had previously attempted using a property but didn't quite make it work, referencing the parent and then the property ie. dob.bordercolor was the trick, Thanks!!